# how to send the context once in multiple calls to Vertex AI

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm new to Vertex AI and GCP. I use the following Python code for the AI to help me solve English language questions.

```
vertexai.init(project="direct-bonsai-******", location="us-central1")
parameters = {
    "max_output_tokens": 10,
    "temperature": 0.2,
    "top_p": 0.8,
    "top_k": 40
}
model = TextGenerationModel.from_pretrained("text-bison@001")

context = """
You are an English teacher, a student will come up to you with the following as input:
1. A sentence from a book
2. One or more English phrases/idioms the student has picked up from a dictionary. each will include an entry head, a definition, and one or more examples

Your task is to examine each of the given phrases/idioms and determine if any of them are in the sentence and if they share the same meaning.


input: sentence = \"They were the last people you\'d expect to be involved in anything strange or mysterious, because they just didn\'t hold with such nonsense.\"

suggestions = [
    {
        \"phrase\": \"be the last person (to do something)\",
        \"definition\": \"to be the most unlikely person of whom one could think in a particular situation; to be the most unlikely person to do something. (Also literal.) _ Mary is the last person you should ask to chair the meeting—she’s so shy.\"
    },
    {
        \"phrase\": \"involve someone in something\",
        \"definition\": \"to draw someone into a matter or problem. _ Please don’t involve me in this mess. _ I do not wish to involve myself in Alice’s business. _I didn’t want to involve you in the problem we are having with the police.\"
    }
]
output: (0, \'B1\')

"""

def generate_response(sentence, suggestions):
    response = model.predict(
        f"""{context}
    input: sentence = \"{sentence}\"
    suggestions = {suggestions}
    """,
        **parameters
    )
    return response.text

for sm in ipm:
    print(f"Response from Model: {generate_response(sm['sentence'], sm['suggestions'])}")
```

I'd like to add 100 more input/output examples to the context, to get more accurate results from the AI. Also, ipm list has more than 5000 items (5000 + API calls).

Is there a way I can only send the context once in the first API call, and after that only send the input? I need to do this to cut down the cost of running this application.